# Downloading Image from URL - from AWS S3 on flutter and saving it to the gallery FLUTTER

Tags: django, flutter, amazon-s3

So prior to switching to AWS S3. I was using Gallery saver (https://pub.dev/packages/gallery_saver)

I switched to hosting media files on AWS S3 (with django as my back end) and was trying to download an image. I pass in the URL(signed URL) that points to the media file in my aws s3 bucket and now its not downloading the image and saving it to the gallery.

this is what I was using before, no code has changed:

```
await GallerySaver.saveImage(url);
```

is there any other way to save images from a url link to an AWS S3 object to your gallery in flutter.  Am I doing something wrong?

The image it self loads perfectly in flutter using CachedNetworkImage so I know the URL works and when I click the url in the browser, I'm able to access/download the image.

I realized the error is : OS Error: File name too long, errno = 36)
so long URL is causing this

Comment: Hi Karan, I have this issue as well, how did you solve this?

Comment: https://github.com/CarnegieTechnologies/gallery_saver/pull/183

Comment: Thanks! How do you pull a fork?

Comment: gallery_saver:
    git:
      url: github url

Comment: I tried   gallery_saver:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/CarnegieTechnologies/gallery_saver

but I still get the Filename too long error, am I pulling from the right link?

Comment: hey sorry did you get it to work? 
https://github.com/ertgrulll/gallery_saver

Comment: Hi Karan! Thanks for your reply again :) I still can't pull your fork, probably because I don't have access rights to your repository (my github name is Charlesvandamme). This is the error I get from ur url:

fatal: ertgrulll/gallery_saver' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
exit code: 128